# Installing Inkscape on Mavericks

Tags: x11, osx-mavericks, inkscape

I have installed Inkscape 0.48.2 on my brand new mac mini running Mavericks but I can never get it to work as it crashes. It once asked me about the X11 server which I have installed but it never worked ever since. What should I do?

Comment: You may want to check the [`Console`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_(OS_X)) app to see what is going wrong with Inkscape and Mavericks...

Comment: defaults[21092]: The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleAquaColorVariant) does not exist
defaults[21094]: 
The domain/default pair of (kCFPreferencesAnyApplication, AppleHighlightColor) does not exist
defaults[21103]: 
The domain/default pair of (.GlobalPreferences, AppleCollationOrder) does not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you installed Xquartz for the X server.  http://xquartz.macosforge.org/

To see the logs you can try from the command line:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/Inkscape
```

Comment: It complains about the locale and it exits if ran from console. I tried running the same command from xterm and it works!! However, it seems to be a pain to start it from the command line each time.

Comment: Did you try running it as a different user by any chance? Logout and login as a different user and then run it.  Looks like it's related to your MacOS X settings.

Comment: Just saw your message. I have already restarted and it works!! It is a shame that in 2014 I need to restart on a Mac. Thank you though.